# Why doesn't the Templar Order care about the 2nd disaster?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, assassins-creed-series

The templars know that the 2nd disaster is coming - they surely must after accessing the ancestral memories of Desmond, Clay Kazmercik and Daniel Cross, and observing the interactions between the ancestors and the First Civilization. A comic even tells us that Daniel Cross read Minerva's prophecy from the [Prophet's Codex](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Prophet%27s_Codex) to Vidic himself.

So why do they not care at all that a world-changing event is about to destroy what they care about most - order?

Could it be possible that in addition to controlling the world, the Templar Satellite also was designed to prevent the 2012 coronal mass ejection?

Comment: I have played every Assassins Creed game and I still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Colin http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/2012_coronal_mass_ejection

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine did you get the chance to check out my answer? I would love some feedback to see if I can improve the answer.

Comment: @Timelord Do *not* spoiler text that is central to the question.  We don't dance around asking a question.  Adding spoiler tags to parts of the question necessary to answer it is counterproductive.  To that end, I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Well I had the same question has you, but after thinking about it I came to this conclusion:

**The Templars did not know about the incoming tragedy.**

> **So why do they not care at all that a world-changing event is about to**
> **destroy what they care about most - order?**

We can't say for sure that they didn't try, because the satellite was probably their idea to prevent the tragedy.

> The Templars set about gathering the remaining Pieces to ensure
> "absolute peace", although they soon found themselves in a race
> against the Assassin Order to obtain the Pieces first.
>
> They planned to send a satellite with a Piece mounted on it into
> orbit, with the launch scheduled on 21 December 2012. Ultimately,
> Abstergo cancelled the launch of the satellite as they were unable to
> obtain the required Piece of Eden in time.

So maybe this was their try to save the planet. Even the **Minerva** says that they wasted away their time (to save the planet) fighting each other (Assassins vs Templars).

> "I had hoped you might find this place – and finish our work. But it
> is too late. You and the Templars have squabbled over our refuse. You
> have wasted centuries. And so you have lost your chance. You cannot
> hope to stop the end now, Desmond. Only to survive it."
>
> **―Minerva, to  Desmond Miles.**

But the satellite was an Abstergo Project called [**Eye-Abstergo**](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Eye-Abstergo).

> This satellite was planned to ensure that a New World Order would be
> enforced on Earth with the Piece of Eden's powers.
>
> "If we were to place just one Piece of Eden within a satellite and
> angle it toward the Earth... well, utopia would be within our grasp."
>
> **―Warren Vidic.**
>
> Upon entering low Earth orbit, the Eye would amplify the Apple of
> Eden's power, as well as boost Abstergo's observational capabilities,
> and locate "individuals with potential."
>
> Though highly uncertain, preliminary analysis suggested that the
> satellite would allow the harvesting of raw data, and would "awaken in
> humans what should have been ours from the moment of our creation."

But it doesn't make sense since Abstergo planned to launch it **December 21, 2012**

So honestly, my answer is: **The Templars did not know about the incoming tragedy.**

Their plans just don't add up and Ubisoft isn't stupid not to notice that big of a plot hole.

The Templars interpretation of Minervas Speech must have been off.

Comment: I can elaborate the answer more with some theories of mine but I'm afraid it will create a long answer and theories aren't quite answers. If the poster wants them I'll add them in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept your answer because simply I just don't buy it. Precisely you said *Their plans just don't add up* and I agree, they don't. They aren't stupid and we see again and again how much they care about what the old ones say. It is frankly impossible for them to miss what the old ones are trying to tell everyone (2nd disaster). But +1 for the effort.